# C# DataGridView Reentrant call issue

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

C# winforms

I have a `DataGridView` populated from a list of objects.  The `DataGridView`is set to use fullrowselect with multiselect off.

I have a button above the table that they can use to select the next row.  I have a `Checkbox` above the table that they use to change data in one of the cells of the selected row.  The `button` and the `Checkbox` both work independently without issue.

I'd like to make it so that when they check that `Checkbox` it changes the data in the selected row cell and then selects the next row in the table.

No matter how I go about this, I either get the reentrant call error immediately or when I later try to select that row again.

I have tried `BeginInvoke`, `BackGroundWorker`, using a timer to change the row selection, setting a variable to remember the row and changing the value after the row selection has changed or after the row has validated.  Every attempt gives me the same error.

My code is much too long to post here, but I may be able to create a simple app to demonstrate the issue if needed.

Please help.

Here is the code:

```
private void chkDone_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ProcedureCode proc = getCode(gridCodes.SelectedRows[0].Cells[3].Value + "");
        proc.done = chkDone.Checked;
        setPnlProgress();
        if(chkDone.Checked)
        {
            btnNext_Click(sender, e);
        }
    }

private void btnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int cRow = gridCodes.SelectedRows[0].Index;
        if (cRow < gridCodes.RowCount - 1)
        {           
            gridCodes.CurrentCell = gridCodes[0, cRow + 1];
        }
    }
```

Here is a screenshot of the table and checkbox:[Click to see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2MNzt.png)

The second `checkbox` labled Done is the one that changes the value in the cell of the selected row.  The third circle `button` selects the next row.

Comment: without any code it is very difficult to post an answer

Comment: If they both work independently without using a BackGroundWorker or anything else couldn't you just get the button press code (go to next row) and put it under your checkbox code? Or make a function and call it with button press and on the bottom of the checkbox code. As GuidoG said, its hard to help you without code so this might not even be close to an answer.

Comment: EpicKip,  I tried both of those workarounds before posting this question, but still wind up with the same error.  Thank you

Comment: A simple app would help. I'm struggling to understand what you are trying to do there with a checkbox.

Comment: First, create a method nextClick and call this. Your code is very ugly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the the checkbox CheckChanged event was being fired when I went to the next row as well as when the user clicked the checkbox.  I added a flag to skip any action during the row entering phase and this resolved the reentrant error.